# Ruby regex to allow for alphanumber and & symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, gsub

I have a piece of our code `gsub(/[^-\p{Alnum}]/i, '')` which seems to remove all symbols and characters from a string. We want to allow for usage of `&` in a string too though. How can we add this in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
gsub(/[^\p{Alnum}&-]/, '')
```

Note: Kept `-` as your original regex had it, removed case insensitivity as it's not needed.

Comment: I've seen the question "Why the downvote?" 1,243 times. 3 of those were answered.  Probably the downvoter punished you for omitting the `i` flag, not realizing it has no effect.

Comment: @CarySwoveland oh well, I was genuinely curious whether this doesn't cover any case. Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: Also maybe add a bit of information (albeit obvious in this case) such as "you just need to add `&` to the character class like so ...". It is possible the downvotes might be for low quality answer/could have been a comment type thing. Also might be that people are distasteful of you answering such a simple question, which is certainly not in the new spirit of SO (yang +1)

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej If I needed to allow `-` in the strings as well, how would you manipulate it? What docs do you use so I can poke in as well?